# построчная работа с текстом

Tags: c++

Есть переменная типа string, инициализированная таким образом:

`std::string str = "qwert\n"
                   "khrkrvne\n"
                   "hbkb124f";`

Каждая строчка отделена от другой "\n". Как работать с каждой строчкой по отдельности?

Comment: Плюс множество вариантов здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129 (целых 68 ответов)

Comment: Что значит "работать по отдельности"? Найдите точки разделения подстрок и "работайте" на здоровье "по отдельности" сколько угодно, в чем проблема-то? Если же вам нужно явно разобрать строку на кусочки - то так и говорите.

Answer (score 3):

```
istringstream input(str);
vector<string> vs;
for (string line; getline(input, line); ) {
    vs.push_back(line);
}
```

и делайте со строками в `vs` что хотите...